# Linux pass command to jump server

Tags: linux, ssh

The flow is like this.

client A -> jump server B -> server C

If I want to connect to jump server B. I can use

```
ssh <user>@<jump-server>
```

After enter the jump server, it have the terminal request you to enter the ip (server C) to connect.

How can I passing the input to the jump server terminal directly?
I had try

```
ssh -t <user>@<jump-server> '<server>'
```

But this does not work.
The solution that what I want is directly connect to server C without any typing every time.
No matter it is pure ssh or linux script.

Comment: Does the default logic with `ssh userC@serverC -o ProxyJump=userB@serverB` works? Or the short form `ssh userC@serverC -J userB@serverB`

Comment: It's not work also, I only have user password for jump server but not the internal server C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you could solve it with `expect`.

**my-expect-script.exp**

```
spawn ssh <user>@<jump-server>
send "<serverC-IP>\n"
interact
```

Start it with:

```
expect my-expect-script.exp
```

To install expect use `sudo apt install expect`

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up in your ~/.ssh/config file. It would look something like this,

```
Host <server>
  ProxyJump <jumpserver>
  User <username>
```

Comment: it's not work for my case, and I did not have the user password for server C